# capturing layout content as image

Tags: gtk

I have put some images on GtkLayout, i want to capture the entire content of the GtkLayout as an image. How can i do in gtk.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Pixbufs.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-from-drawable) on the `GtkLayout`'s `GdkWindow`. See [this explanation of how to do it in PHP-GTK.](http://php-gtk.eu/code-hints/grabbing-a-screenshot-with-gdk)

Comment: Why not anybody have +1 that answer.Afer a long time 2014 I found this useful.